# Bot Userstate empty when loaded

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, botframework, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the Microsoft Bot Framework v4.4.5 and when running the bot in Azure / localhost emulator it seems like the UserState stored in blob storage is empty in the turncontext / bot.
 The state object only contains default data, i.e. strings are empty.

When memory storage is used, everything works fine and state data is stored in memory and contains the correct values.

In OnMembersAddedAsync _userState.SaveChangesAsync saves the correct state to blob storage.

Getting the client in OnTurnAsync always returns the default value of the ClientProfile.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Error handling
            services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, BotErrorAdapter>();

            const string storageContainer = "#Name#";
            IStorage dataStore = new AzureBlobStorage("#ConnectionString#", storageContainer);

            // Bot registration
            services.AddBot<Bot>(options =>
            {
                options.CredentialProvider = new ConfigurationCredentialProvider(_configuration);
            });

            services.AddHttpClient();

            var conversationState = new ConversationState(dataStore);
            var userState = new UserState(dataStore);

            services.AddSingleton(conversationState);
            services.AddSingleton(userState);

            services.AddSingleton(_configuration);
        }
```

Bot.cs:

```
        private IStorage _storage;
        private BotState _userState;

        public QnaBot(UserState userState, IStorage storage)
        {            
            _userState = userState;
            _storage = storage;
        }

        public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            if (turnContext.Activity.Type is ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                string userInput = turnContext.Activity.Text;

                // LoadAsync doesn't seem to set any data
                await _userState.LoadAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);

                var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<ClientProfile>(nameof(ClientProfile));
                var client = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ClientProfile());

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"You wrote {userInput}, Session {client.Name}");

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Content {content}");
            }
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<ClientProfile>(nameof(ClientProfile));
            var client = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ClientProfile());

            if (!client.FetchedData)
            {
                client.Name = "MyName";
                client.FetchedData = true;

                await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            }

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Hi my name is {client.Name}");
        }
```

ClientProfile.cs:

```
        public class ClientProfile
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state data in the other method as well. Just like you mentioned is being done in the `OnMembersAddedAsync` method (`await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);`), you need to do in the `OnTurnAsync` method.

Currently, it is loading userState data:
`await _userState.LoadAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);`

But you need to save it at the end of the method:

```
await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

    if (turnContext.Activity.Type is ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
    string userInput = turnContext.Activity.Text;

                    // LoadAsync doesn't seem to set any data
                    await _userState.LoadAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);

                    var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<ClientProfile>(nameof(ClientProfile));
                    var client = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ClientProfile());

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"You wrote {userInput}, Session {client.Name}");

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Content {content}");

                    //Add this line
                    await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
                }
```